# String manipulation in C#: strip a path using the characters after each numeric value

Tags: c#, string

Given an input string, I would like to get the output from this in the specified format: `filename;path`.

For the input string `/vob/TEST/.@@/main/ch_vobsweb/1/VOBSWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/4/VobsWebUI/main/ch_vobsweb/2/VaultWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/2/func.js`

I expect this output string:
`func.js;VOBSWeb/VosWebUI/VaultWeb/func.js`

The filename is listed at the end of the whole string, and its path is supposed to be stripped using the characters after each numeric value (eg. `/1/VOBSWeb/` and then `/4/VobsWebUI` and then `/2/vaultWeb`)

Comment: I think main/ch_vobsweb is common after @@ so is try replacing it with string.replace

Comment: @Daniel: Speak for yourself; someone already wrote it for him. If it makes you feel better, it wasn't a very efficient or maintainable solution.

Comment: @Steven are you referring to my solution as not efficient and not maintainable?

Comment: Please post the code you have written so far. People generally do not like to just write your code for you.

Comment: Does the input always start with `/`? Can it end with `/`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [String manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420967/string-manipulation)

Comment: Merged; please don't double-post

Comment: And now since you have the power to upvote (and to leave comments), please let us know if any of us are on the right track to solving your rather vaguely stated problem.

Answer (score 1):

If the number of paths is arbitrary, then you need a two-step approach:

---

**First**, remove all the "uninteresting stuff" from the string.

Search for `.*?/\d+/([^/]+/?)` and replace all with `$1`.

In C#: `resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @".*?/\d+/([^/]+/?)", "$1");`

In JavaScript: `result = subject.replace(/.*?\/\d+\/([^\/]+\/?)/g, "$1");`

This will transform your string into `VOBSWeb/VobsWebUI/VaultWeb/func.js`.

---

**Second**, copy the filename to the front of the string.

Search for `(.*/)([^/]+)$` and replace with `$2;$1$2`.

C#: `resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "(.*/)([^/]+)$", "$2;$1$2");`

JavaScript: `result = subject.replace(/(.*\/)([^\/]+)$/g, "$2;$1$2");`

This will transform the result of the previous operation into `func.js;VOBSWeb/VobsWebUI/VaultWeb/func.js`

---

If the number of paths is constant, then you can do it in a single regex:

Search for `^.*?/\d+/([^/]+/).*?/\d+/([^/]+/).*?/\d+/([^/]+/).*?/\d+/([^/]+)`

and replace with `$4;$1$2$3$4`.

C#: `resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"^.*?/\d+/([^/]+/).*?/\d+/([^/]+/).*?/\d+/([^/]+/).*?/\d+/([^/]+)", "$4;$1$2$3$4");`

JavaScript: `result = subject.replace(/^.*?\/\d+\/([^\/]+\/).*?\/\d+\/([^\/]+\/).*?\/\d+\/([^\/]+\/).*?\/\d+\/([^\/]+)/g, "$4;$1$2$3$4");`

This regex will be inefficient if the string fails to match; this could be improved with atomic grouping, but JavaScript doesn't support that.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a split() function on strings that returns an array, so I think that's probably a good starting point for what you're going for.

Comment: FYI: This question used to have a javascript tag, not a C# tag, before it was merged.

Comment: Wanted to have the same sortedout in Javascript if possible

Answer (score 0):

Assuming its not an arbitrary number of paths you can use regular expressions:

Find this:

```
.*[0-9]/([a-zA-Z]*)/[^0-9]*[0-9]/([a-zA-Z]*)/[^0-9]*[0-9]/([a-zA-Z]*)/[^0-9]*[0-9]/([a-zA-Z.]*)/
```

Then use the groupings to write the new string:

```
\4;\1/\2/\3/\4
```