# Regular Expression to pull a path/filename from a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Given an input string, I would like to get the output from this in the specified format: `filename;path`.

For the input string:

```
/vob/TEST/.@@/main/ch_vobsweb/1/VOBSWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/4/VobsWebUI/main/ch_vobsweb/2/VaultWeb/main/ch_vobsweb/2/func.js
```

I expect this output string:

```
func.js;VOBSWeb/VosWebUI/VaultWeb/func.js
```

The filename is listed at the end of the whole string, and its path is supposed to be stripped using the characters after each numeric value (eg. `/1/VOBSWeb/` and then `/4/VobsWebUI` and then `/2/vaultWeb`)

> **Related:**
>   This is related to an earlier C# question, but this time using JavaScript:  [String manipulation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420967/string-manipulation)

Comment: Tried
/[0-9]/[a-zA-Z]*
but this returns with the numeric value . I need to exculde the same.

Comment: @Raj - if you have more detail, edit your question and add it, instead of posting it as a comment.

Comment: Is it always four parts, or is the number of parts variable?

Comment: @Raj, three times now in the last two days you appear to have asked the same question. The second was even merged with the first. Voting to close as dupe. If you continue that behaviour, you're likely to be suspended (not a threat especially since that power is not mine to wield, I'm just letting you know a possible outcome).

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate if you sense so. This is an help required usig Javascript . I was possibly looking the best way to present the info.
The flow is from C# to Web Page. I either have an option to do this iN ASP.net or at the browser level and hence this question.

I don't want to spam questions , this definitely is a nuisance, but without understanding the very need to posting the same question in a different tag means something.

Comment: Apologies, I didn't notice that the tags had changed.

Answer (score 1):

Since I almost finished typing it in anyway, here's the condensed version:

```
result = subject.replace(/\/?(?:[^\/\d]+\/)+\d+\/([^\/]+\/?)/g, "$1")
                .replace(/^.*\/([^\/]+)$/, "$1;$0");
```

Answer (score 0):

Never mind ,this has been answered in an earlier post by Tim

First, remove all the "uninteresting stuff" from the string.

Search for `.*?/\d+/([^/]+/?)` and replace all with `$1`

In C#: `resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @".*?/\d+/([^/]+/?)", "$1");`

In JavaScript: `result = subject.replace(/.*?\/\d+\/([^\/]+\/?)/g, "$1");`

This will transform your string into

> VOBSWeb/VobsWebUI/VaultWeb/func.js

---

Second, copy the filename to the front of the string.

Search for `(.*/)([^/]+)$` and replace with `$2;$1$2`

C#: `resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, "(.*/)([^/]+)$", "$2;$1$2");`

JavaScript: `result = subject.replace(/(.*\/)([^\/]+)$/g, "$2;$1$2");`

This will transform the result of the previous operation into

> func.js;VOBSWeb/VobsWebUI/VaultWeb/func.js